# iPhone Full screen camera uiimagepickercontroller preview

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller, fullscreen, scale

In iOS3 to get a full screen preview a scale of 1.12412 was enough.

CGFloat cameraTransformX = 1.12412;
CGFloat cameraTransformY = 1.12412;

```
picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(picker.cameraViewTransform, cameraTransformX, cameraTransformY);
```

}
Scaling x and y to avoid distortion.

In iOS4 using this scaling leaves a black bar at the bottom of the screen????
http://educoelho.com/files/configurePicker_SecondAttempt.png

Also the captured photo is not centered to what you see bacause the preview is shifted

Anyone familiar with this issue?
What is the iOS4 method for a iOS3.x full screen preview?

See also [UIImagePickerController cameraViewTransform acts differently in iOS 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407986/uiimagepickercontroller-cameraviewtransform-acts-differently-in-ios-4)