# How to calculate cameraViewTransform for iPhone4,iPhone5 and iPad dynamically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

How to set transforms for different iOS devices (iPhone4, iPhone5 and iPad) dynamically?

```
UIImagePickerController *pickerImage = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
pickerImage.cameraViewTransform = ??
```

I did it by having hard coded checks for different iOS devices (iPhone4, iPhone5 and iPad) with iOS 7.0 and older version.

```
if (([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad))
{ // For iPad
    _pickerImage.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(_pickerImage.cameraViewTransform, 1.0, 1.0);
}
else
{ // For iPhone
    if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
    { // iPhone5 ~ 4.0 inch
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7.0)
            { // For older than iOS 7.0
                _pickerImage.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(_pickerImage.cameraViewTransform, 1, 1.4);                  
            }
            else
            { // For iOS 7.0 and later
                _pickerImage.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(_pickerImage.cameraViewTransform, 1, 1.67);                    
            }
    }
    else
    { // iPhone4 ~ 3.5 inch
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7.0)
        {
            _pickerImage.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(_pickerImage.cameraViewTransform, 1.0, 1.25);
        }
        else
        { // For iOS 7.0 and later
            _pickerImage.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(_pickerImage.cameraViewTransform, 1.0, 1.0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please refer to my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407986/uiimagepickercontroller-cameraviewtransform-acts-differently-in-ios-4/24163460#24163460
You don't need to scale if, just translate it.